# Batch (xcopy all files to folder) with loop

Tags: windows, command-line, loops, batch-file, xcopy

can anyone help me with loop in batch for windows? i want make script that will allow me to do something like this:

```
1. copy all folders and files from Drive I: to X:\folder0001;
2. when done display: "Done"; (i ejected cd)
3. "enter" to next copy;

1. copy all folders and files from Drive I: to X:\folder0002;
2. when done display: "Done"; (i ejected cd)
3. "enter" to next copy;

...

1. copy all folders and files from Drive I: to X:\folder0010;
2. when done display: "Done"; (i ejected cd)
3. "enter" to next copy;


button q = exit
```

copy i do with changing manually number with command:

> for %%f in (i:) do xcopy %%f
>   X:\folder001\ /e,

i want only press enter and change cd

but i dont know how to create this script :(

Comment: Are you always copying the same thing but to a different folder name on X: each time (x:\folder0001, x:\folder0002 and so on)?

Comment: Yes, always from (the same I:\\) cdrom to different folder name on disk (X:\folder0001, folder0002...). Thank You! It Works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set number=1
FOR /L %%C IN (1,1,100) DO (
  set dest=!number!
  for %%N in (9999 999 99 9) do if !number! LEQ %%N set dest=0!dest!
  xcopy I\*.*I:\folder!dest!" /E /I
  ECHO *** CHANGE CD OR CTRL-C TO QUIT****
  PAUSE
  set /a number+=1
)
```

I don't think there's a way to check input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the help here but at least some :)

```
@echo off
if %1. == . GOTO NOPARM
if %2. == . GOTO NOPARM

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD %1*') XCOPY %%G %2 /e

GOTO END

:NOPARM
echo missing folder name

:END
```

the message is missing... don't know how to pause it on every iteration :(